# Share YouTube running Videos from Mobile to Panasonic Viera Smart TV

Tags: smart-tv

How to share currently playing YouTube Videos in Android mobile to Panasonic Viera Smart TV? Unfortunately YouTube App is not working in my Panasonic Smart TV model. Is there any In-Built App to download from Google PlayStore and share the same from mobile to TV without relying on ChromeCast or any other external hardware devices. Are there any best Possibilities?

Comment: Since you mention Play Store, I presume you're talking anout Android. Recent Android version have screen mirroring built in, which works with Panasonic Viera smart TVs if they support it. I'd like to ask you to include relevant information in qour question next time.

Comment: @ClassStacker: What Information you're expected to include?

Comment: @ClassStacker Both android and tvs are off-topic here ...

Comment: @DavidPostill You're right. Thanks for pointing this out.